# Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<ReactNodeLike>'

Tags: reactjs

i have project, when i open App file, i get this error, i don't know why, please solve my problem:

Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable'.
Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ReactElementLike'.
Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
Type 'Key | null' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.tsx(26, 3): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InferPropsInner<Pick<{ children: Validator<NonNullable>; }, "children">> & Partial<...>'

is there any problem in my package.json versions:

```
{
  "name": "virtualFairs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/charts": "^1.4.2",
    "@ant-design/colors": "^6.0.0",
    "@ant-design/compatible": "^1.1.2",
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.6.2",
    "@ant-design/plots": "^1.1.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.8",
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "ant-design": "^1.0.0",
    "antd": "^4.16.9",
    "antd-img-crop": "^3.16.0",
    "array-move": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.19.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.9.1",
    "craco-less": "^1.18.0",
    "depcheck": "^1.4.3",
    "firebase": "^8.8.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "formik-antd": "^2.0.4",
    "gsap": "^3.7.1",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "prism-react-renderer": "^1.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rc-queue-anim": "^1.8.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-auth-code-input": "^3.2.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.33.5",
    "react-bottom-scroll-listener": "^5.0.0",
    "react-code-input": "^3.10.1",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dnd": "^14.0.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^14.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.4",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-highlight-words": "^0.18.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-image-timeline": "^3.2.13",
    "react-images": "^1.2.0-beta.7",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-intl": "^5.20.6",
    "react-notifications-component": "^3.1.0",
    "react-player": "^2.14.1",
    "react-query": "^3.39.1",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-share": "^4.4.0",
    "react-simple-maps": "^2.3.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "react-svg-piechart": "^2.4.2",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
    "react-trello": "^2.2.11",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "recharts": "^2.0.10",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reqwest": "^2.0.5",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.6",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3",
    "use-url-search-params": "^2.3.13",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "craco --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.+(js|jsx)\"",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix \"src/**/*.+(js|jsx)\"",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.+(js|jsx)\"",
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "not ie 11",
      "not chrome < 51",
      "not safari < 10",
      "not android < 51"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^13.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.42",
    "@types/react": "17.0.39",
    "@types/react-csv": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-simple-maps": "^1.0.8",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.8",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.14",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "commitlint-config-jira": "^1.5.1",
    "commitlint-plugin-jira-rules": "^1.5.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import './shared/styles/crema.less';
import {
  AppContextProvider,
  AppLayout,
  AppLocaleProvider,
  AppThemeProvider,
  AuthRoutes,
} from './domain';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthContextProvider from './pages/auth/context';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppContextProvider>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <AppThemeProvider>
            <AppLocaleProvider>
              <BrowserRouter>
                <AuthRoutes>
                  <AppLayout />
                </AuthRoutes>
              </BrowserRouter>
            </AppLocaleProvider>
          </AppThemeProvider>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </AppContextProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post your code. However, based the error, it sounds like you're trying to pass a number in for a "key" when the type of key is "string | null".